# how to convert Nested Json to CSV file

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to write a Json file to CSV but having trouble as it is split up into a hierarchy.

the below is an example of one of the branches and then it repeats by store to build a table showing footfall for each store.

would it be best to use python to split this into a CSV?
The flatten function does not return the right structure although i might be doing it wrong i am not sure, any help would be appreciated it!

Thanks,

Json Code Example

```
{
  "sites": [
    {
      "storeID": "Store 1",
      "siteTraffic": [
        {
          "traffic": [
            {
              "startTime": "000000",
              "enters": "1",
              "exits": "6",
              "code": "02"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "010000",
              "enters": "4",
              "exits": "2",
              "code": "02"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "020000",
              "enters": "1",
              "exits": "1",
              "code": "02"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "030000",
              "enters": "1",
              "exits": "0",
              "code": "02"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "040000",
              "enters": "11",
              "exits": "4",
              "code": "02"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "050000",
              "enters": "38",
              "exits": "8",
              "code": "02"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "060000",
              "enters": "82",
              "exits": "25",
              "code": "02"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "070000",
              "enters": "185",
              "exits": "74",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "080000",
              "enters": "532",
              "exits": "286",
              "code": "02"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "090000",
              "enters": "1280",
              "exits": "766",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "100000",
              "enters": "1927",
              "exits": "1443",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "110000",
              "enters": "2539",
              "exits": "2109",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "120000",
              "enters": "3070",
              "exits": "2790",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "130000",
              "enters": "3354",
              "exits": "3347",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "140000",
              "enters": "3066",
              "exits": "3105",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "150000",
              "enters": "3057",
              "exits": "3192",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "160000",
              "enters": "2710",
              "exits": "3070",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "170000",
              "enters": "2411",
              "exits": "2846",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "180000",
              "enters": "1392",
              "exits": "2111",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "190000",
              "enters": "788",
              "exits": "1097",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "200000",
              "enters": "249",
              "exits": "431",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "210000",
              "enters": "75",
              "exits": "137",
              "code": "01"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "220000",
              "enters": "19",
              "exits": "113",
              "code": "02"
            },
            {
              "startTime": "230000",
              "enters": "9",
              "exits": "49",
              "code": "02"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

I have tried everything but can't seem to flatten it to get the below table using python/jupyter notebook

```
Date           Store ID     Traffic Start Time  Enters  Exits   Code
26/09/2023  Store 1          000000                 1   6   02
26/09/2023  Store 1          010000                 4   2   02
26/09/2023  Store 1          020000                 1   1   02
26/09/2023  Store 1          030000                 1   0   02
```

Comment: Do you want to do this via the CSV package or the Pandas package or some other way?

Comment: this has been resolved now thank you i am not sure where the answer has disappeared to